# Symfony - Embedded Collection Form validation conditionally

Tags: symfony

I have a carousel with a collection of slides (OneToMany) and each slide contain a file that I have to validate if not exist.

When a slide has no file, the field is required but when the file exist, it's not required.

My CarouselType:

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('slides', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => SlideType::class,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'prototype' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'row_attr' => [
                'class' => 'hidden'
            ]
        ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Carousel::class,
        ]);
    }
```

My SlideType:

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', TextType::class, [
                'row_attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-group'
                ],
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                ],
                'required' => false
            ])
            ->add('url', UrlType::class, [
                'row_attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-group'
                ],
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                ],
                'required' => false
            ])
            ->add('file', FileType::class, [
                'row_attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-group'
                ],
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                ],
                'required' => false
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Slide::class,
            'validation_groups' => function (FormInterface $form) {
                $data = $form->getData();

                if ($data->getFile() === null && $data->getFileName() === null) {
                    return ['upload'];
                }

                return ['Default'];
            },
        ]);
    }
```

My Carousel Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CarouselRepository::class)
 */
class Carousel
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(
     *     targetEntity=Slide::class,
     *     mappedBy="carousel",
     *     fetch="EXTRA_LAZY",
     *     orphanRemoval=true,
     *     cascade={"persist"}
     * )
     * @Assert\Count(min=1, minMessage="carousel.slides.count.min")
     * @Assert\Valid(groups={"upload"})
     */
    private $slides;

    ...
    ...
}
```

My Slide Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=SlideRepository::class)
 */
class Slide
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $url;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $fileName;

    /**
     * @var UploadedFile
     * @Assert\NotNull(message="slide.file.not_null", groups={"upload"})
     */
    protected $file;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Carousel::class, inversedBy="slides")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $carousel;

    ...
    ...
}
```

I've added `validation_groups` in my SlideType but it's not working.
What's wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [PreSetData Event](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#adding-an-event-subscriber-to-a-form-class) for adding `file` in the SlideType

```
   $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $isNotRequired = ($data instanceof Slide) && $data->getUrl();
        $constraints = isNotRequired ? [] : [new NotBlank()];
       
        $event->getForm()->add('file', FileType::class, [
            'row_attr' => [
                'class'   => 'form-group'
            ],
            'attr' => [
                'class'   => 'form-control'
            ],
            'required'    => !$isNotRequired,
            'constraints' => $constraints,
        ]);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use "valid" to validate the subform.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html

```
$builder->add('slides', CollectionType::class, [
        'entry_type' => SlideType::class,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'allow_delete' => true,
        'prototype' => true,
        'by_reference' => false,
        'row_attr' => [
            'class' => 'hidden'
        ],
        'constraints' => [new Valid()],
    ]);
```

Comment: I already have `@Assert\Valid` constraint in my Carousel entity but it's not working. I also tried with your code in CarouselType and it also does not work.